# iAd framework missing in XCode

Tags: ios, frameworks, iad

I downloaded the latest XCode 3 days ago.

I am trying to add the iAd Framework to my current project.

I go to target, then "link with libraries", click on "+" and have a list of frameworks.

But can't find any iad framework in that list?

See screenshot here:

[image: screenshot]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kn8F.png

Any idea why?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

None of those look like they are iOS libraries.  Make sure your project's other settings point to iOS, not Mac OS.  You also seem to be missing lots of the other iOS frameworks, such as GameKit.  If you have to, click "Add Other" and browse for `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/iAd.framework`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can reference it only by adding in the **Build Setting** -> **Other Linker Flags**   the value **-weak_framework** and after that entrance add in another row **iAD**

This just to make a weak reference to the iAd Framework.